# Create List of Blank Forms on Submit

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms

I am working with Django and have one form for each employee that expires every two weeks. For example, last weeks timesheets are now expired and I need to create a list of new timesheets.

How can I create multiple blank forms, based on creation of new time period?

Context:

```
class TwoWeekPeriod(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateField(_("Start Date"))
    end_date = models.DateField(_("End Date"))
    week_number = models.IntegerField(_("Week Number"))

class CreateNewTimesheet(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateField(_("Start Date"))
    end_date = models.DateField(_("End Date"))
    two_week_period = models.ForeignKey(TwoWeekPeriod, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        week_number = (self.start_date - timezone.now().date()).days // 14 + 1
        two_week_period, _ = TwoWeekPeriod.objects.get_or_create(
            start_date=self.start_date,
            end_date=self.end_date,
            defaults={'week_number': week_number}
        )
        self.two_week_period = two_week_period
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Employee Timesheet example:

```
class Foo(model.Models)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    time_in = ###
    time_out = ###
```

How can I use `CreateNewTimesheet`, let’s say 14 (each employee) blank forms using model  `Foo` for each employee in order to input new time, for each employee, for the next two week period, without having to create each individual timesheet manually?

Comment: Use a `FormSet`. A model named `CreateNew...` makes not much sense.

Comment: I use forms based on these models with Django Crispy Forms.

Comment: are you asking how to make an arbitrary number of records in one action or how to automatically create records every two weeks?

Comment: Probably a formset would come in handy, but your model structure creates a lot of questions.  Are users adding time/hours for each day of their pay period?  Are there associated job numbers or cost numbers to bill to?  Lots of ways to do this.

Comment: I need to create a blank list of forms each two weeks for employees. So say there are 14 employees, 14 new forms would be created, listed and displayed in a template without having to create each  timesheet manually every 2 weeks. It would be adding hours everyday, including time in and out but twice in a day if they get called back in. I have the timesheet model, it is just about getting the blank forms created and displayed once new timesheet period is created. I just don’t want to have to manually create 14 individual timesheets upon the new 2 week period.

Answer (score 0):

Do this on the view function:

```py
class NewPayPeriodCreate(CreateView): # class based view
    model = TwoWeekPeriod
    template_name = "form.html"
    form_class = TwoWeekPeriodForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('app_name:success_url_name')

    def form_valid(self, form):  # override the action that occurs when valid form data has been POSTed.
        response = super().form_valid(form) # do the default actions of the function, which includes saving the TwoWeekPeriod object

        employee_queryset = Employee.objects.all()
        for employee in employee_queryset:
            CreateNewTimesheet.objects.create(
                employee=employee,
                start_date=self.object.start_date, # access the TwoWeekPeriod object just created with 'self.object'
                end_date=self.object.end_date,
                two_week_period=self.object
            )

        return response
```

note that this is 1 database query for each employee and so if you have a lot of employees there may be performance considerations.

remove the overridden `save` in `CreateNewTimesheet`. Since you need to make multiple `CreateNewTimesheet` records you cannot start from one of those records - if you wanted to do an overridden save you would do it in `TwoWeekPeriod`.

Just note that bulk actions do not use a model's save function.